# Custom producer consumer randomly stops while using blocking collection

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, producer-consumer

I have following problem: Service is being run on the server. It has timer that ticks every 5 seconds. It is being modeled to produce items for a consumer. Items are being consumed in multi thread.
I've added logging but I cannot find out when and where any problem occurs and this just blocks. No exception or error. My goal is to keep getting requests to be processed from db and consume them. Timer is being a producer.

```
public class CustomProducerConsumer<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<T> blockingCollection;
    private readonly Action<T> consumeItem;
    private readonly Task[] workers;

    public CustomProducerConsumer(Action<T> consumeItem,
        int degreeOfParallelism,
        int capacity = 1024)
    {
        this.consumeItem = consumeItem;
        this.blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<T>(capacity);
        this.workers = Enumerable.Range(1, degreeOfParallelism)
                                .Select(_ => Task.Factory.StartNew(Worker,
                                    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning))
                                .ToArray();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Unblock all workers even if the client
        // didn't call CompleteProcessing
        if (!this.blockingCollection.IsAddingCompleted)
        {
            this.blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
        }

        Task.WaitAll(this.workers);
        this.blockingCollection.Dispose();
    }

    public void Process(T item)
    {
        this.blockingCollection.TryAdd(item);
    }

    private void Worker()
    {
        foreach (var item in this.blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            this.consumeItem(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code from service:

```
private readonly BlockingCollection<StitchingRequestProcessingModel> requestsToBeProcessed =
        new BlockingCollection<StitchingRequestProcessingModel>(10);

    private readonly BlockingCollection<Dictionary<int, StitchingRequest[]>> pendingRequests =
        new BlockingCollection<Dictionary<int, StitchingRequest[]>>(10);

    private readonly Timer timer;

    public Service()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.produceConsumer =
            new CustomProducerConsumer<StitchingRequestModel>(this.ProcessItems,
                Environment.ProcessorCount);

        this.timer = new Timer(o =>
        {
            this.TimerElapsed();

            this.timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
        }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
        this.ConsumeRequests();
    }

public void TimerElapsed()
    {
        try
        {
//this just adds into the list an item to ping the db for pending requests when available
            this.requestsToBeProcessed.Add(new StitchingRequestProcessingModel());
            this.pendingRequests.TryTake(out Dictionary<int, Request[]> requests);
            if (requests == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Request[]> request in requests)
            {
                this.produceConsumer.Process(new StitchingRequestModel(request));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            this.errorLogger.Error(exception.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ConsumeRequests()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (!this.requestsToBeProcessed.IsCompleted)
                {

                    if (this.tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    StitchingRequestProcessingModel data = null;
                    try
                    {
                        data = this.requestsToBeProcessed.Take();
                    }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException)
                    {
                    }

                    if (data == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        // this just executes sql query to get those request from db
                        var requests = this.requestService.GetPendingRequests();
                        this.pendingRequests.Add(requests);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        this.errorLogger.Error(exception.Message, "Failed to get pending requests");
                    }
                }
            },
            this.tokenSource.Token,
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current);
    }

    private void ProcessItems(StitchingRequestModel model)
    {
        foreach (StitchingRequest request in model.Requests)
        {
            this.requestsToBeProcessed.Add(new StitchingRequestProcessingModel(request);
        }
    }
```

Main reason why I placed consuming items into blocking collection is Nhibernate. It is giving me issues while doing multithreading. No ideas what else to try, nor why this approach is not working. I do not want to call CompleteAdding on blocking collection since I need requests to be added and just processed in first available thread.

Timer on each elapsed event will try to create an a pending request that will be added into blocking collection and processed on first available turn. Service runs for 2~3h and just stops. ProcessItems method can be long running. CPU is 8 core.

**UPDATE**
Added cancelation for consumer task.

Comment: This is probably unrelated to your problem, but I would avoid using the [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.take) method. I would use the [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable) instead.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias In timerElapsed or ConsumeRequests? ConsumeRequests I need to be processed 1 by 1.

Comment: A possible point of concern is that the collections `requestsToBeProcessed` and `pendingRequests` are bounded (capacity = 10). Is case they are full, the method `Add` will block until there is space available. If there is never space available, the `Add` will block indefinitely.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I am aware of that, but `Take` method removes items from collection. Check `ConsumeRequests`, it is in a while loop so items are removed all the time if there are any. Collection `requestsToBeProcessed` is being checked in `ConsumeRequests` method which is a task, in a while loop. So, even when collection is full it will wait until `ConsumeRequests` takes 1 item from that collection. Am I missing possible place where this can be blocked?

Comment: Does the Service stops - mean, it exists and needs to be started again from Service Manager?  Or is it simply running but not doing anything?

Comment: @Nick Service doesn't stop, but it is not pulling requests from db. It is running, no errors but requests from db are not being pulled at all. `var requests = this.requestService.GetPendingRequests();` it is always 0. I checked db and requests are not being processed at all.

Comment: The problem then might be in the way the database is accessed.  If you are accessing it from different threads, there might be a transaction isolation level issue, for example.  To diagnose, I would try this: create a new connection, run the query, get the result, close the connection (all in plain ADO.NET) and see how it works.

Comment: @Nick `ConsumeRequests` this is the only place from which access to db is being made.

Comment: Nevermind.  Just replace it with plan ADO.NET code as I described to isolate NHibernate and its possible side-effects.

Comment: @Nick It appears you were right, well partially :) I was holding entity object between consumer and producer. After creating a model and just passing necessary info all good. I also made some improvements on code.

Comment: Nice to hear. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved with not working with entity object between consumer and producer. Created dto for info needed.